# error in ssis send mail task for smtp connection

Tags: ssis

> [Send Mail Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
>   message: "Failure sending mail.   System.Net.WebException: Unable to
>   connect to the remote server  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:   No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 127.0.0.1:25".

This is the error I am getting. I have configured my DB mail as it is shown in the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYMBNOE9EQs . What is the solution??

Comment: *No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it*  Sounds like a security/permissions issue?